# VS2015: Default Universal App template causes XAML designer crash

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2015

When I create a Universal App template project in VS2015, it throws an unhandled exception in the designer view (telling me that often times, 'excluding code' will cause less hiccups), then proceeds to give me the following exception:

```
System.OperationCanceledException

The registration of the app package required by the designer took too long
to complete and was canceled. Reload the designer to try again.
```

I've tried rebooting Windows 10, and repairing VS2015. Nothing works! Looking at the 'similar questions' tab makes me think that Microsoft rushed this a little too much..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue with VS2015 community edition on Windows 10.

The following fixed my issue:

1. Disabling developer mode in Windows.
2. Restart.
3. Enabling developer mode.